# Uncaught ReferenceError when initiatizing parameters

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add extra initial values to a javascript to be used in a when dragging 
objects within a web page via the mouse.

When I try and use a global variable that have just been initialised I get the 
following error:

"Uncaught ReferenceError prefixPicSlot is not defined

When I go into the drag functions that are invoked by the mouseup/down events 
these variables are accessible - they don't seem to be 
available within the initialising functions.

Here is the initialization code that gets called:

```
initialize:function()
{

    this.getJsonParams()
    this.getPicnVidImageParams()
    document.onmousedown=this.drag      // Manages when the mouse is down and dragging 
    document.onmouseup=this.videoslot   // Manages when the dragging has been stopped
    $(document).on("change", "form", this.formChange)
    $(document).on("click", "button", this.selectButton)

}, //initialize
```

getJsonParams as its name suggests gets parameters from the server and works fine.

getPicnVidParams is the new initial function that has just been added and uses 
variables setup in getJsonParams to create new variables that are to be used in 
the mouse events. This function works fine when I put it in the this.drag function,
but it is more efficient only to call it once at the start rather than with every mouse event.

Here is the piece of code from getJsonParams that creates the variables 
used in getPicNvidParams and works fine:

```
//Get Admin data....                     
jsAdmin = $.ajax("getJsAdmin" )
.done(function(data, textStatus, jsAdmin) { 
    // Success !!!
    var tmpText = jsAdmin.responseText.replace("[", "")
    tmpText = tmpText.replace("]", "")          
    admin = JSON.parse( tmpText)            
    vidPreviewHtml = admin.vidPreviewHtml
    debugStatus = admin.jsDiagnostics                        
    prefixPicSlot = admin.prefixPicSlot                      
    prefixVidSlot = admin.prefixVidSlot                      
})
.fail(function() { alert("getJsAdmin - error"); })
```

Here first part of the code of getPicnVidParams whjich fails in the first

non-comment line -  firstPicSlot = prefixPicSlot + "0"
...

```
getPicnVidImageParams:function(e){   

// get the important image params from the first picture and 
// video slots display

firstPicSlot = prefixPicSlot + "0"
firstPicSlotElem=document.getElementById(firstPicSlot.toString())
firstPicInnerHTML = firstPicSlotElem.innerHTML
firstPicSlot = "#" + firstPicSlot

firstVidSlot = prefixVidSlot + "0"
firstVidSlotElem=document.getElementById(firstVidSlot.toString())
firstVidInnerHTML = firstVidSlotElem.innerHTML
firstVidSlot = "#" + firstVidSlot

try{ picWidth = $(firstPicSlot).children("img").attr("width")}
catch(err)
{
    alert("FN: getPicnVidImageParams error (picWidth)" 
        + " \n"  +
        " firstPicSlot: "+ firstPicSlot
    ) 
}
```

It seems strange that global variables setup in these initialization functions 
cannot be accessed where their setup yet yet can be seen in the mouse event driven 
functions.

I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Is the callback in getJsonParams() getting executed before this.getPicnVidImageParams()

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that AJAX is asynchronous, so `this.getPicnVidImageParams()` is actually being called before `getJsonParams()` has assigned your variables. You need to put `this.getPicnVidImageParams()` at the end of the `.done` function of your ajax call.

Comment: Yes placing the function call at the end of the .done does the trick - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call in `getJsonParams` is asynchronous (the first 'a' in ajax), which means your javascript program will continue to execute while the HTTP request is made in the background. Basically, `getPicnVidImageParams` is called before the HTTP request completes. Moving the `getPicnVidImageParams` call into the ajax success handler (the `done` function) will give you  the result you want.